# Reading non-standard ASCII file c++

Tags: c++, file

I have a .LEF file which contains a description of an integrated circuit. I can open the file in word pad and it contains ASCII elements.

> ```
> NAMESCASESENSITIVE ON ;
> UNITS
> DATABASE MICRONS 100 ;
> END UNITS
> ```

Now I want to be able to read this file in C++ and print out it's contents.

I have tried

```
cout << LEFfile << '\n';
string line;
ifstream file(LEFfile);
if(file.is_open())
{
    cout << "LEF FILE is open" << '\n';
    while(getline (file,line))
    {
        cout << line << '\n';
    }
    file.close();
}else cout << "unable to open file";
```

and got the output:

> ```
> ks32bit_A.lef
> LEF FILE is open
> ```

Is there another way to open these files? Or am I doing something wrong just in reading the file.

Link: 
https://stellenbosch-my.sharepoint.com/personal/18288928_sun_ac_za/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?folderid=170d32c8bb3f74081b8c1936c2a394370&authkey=Aa8vjntvAURgSJ0i10BXvxA

Comment: In what way is the contents of file non-standard?  Can you open the LEF file in a programmers editor of some sort, and check what the actual byte values in the file are?  (Notepad would be better than wordpad, notepad++ even better).  Is the file unicode text?  What does your debugger say is happening?  Does the first call to getline fail, and if so, what is the state of `file`?

Comment: Can you give a link/upload one of these files?

Comment: are you sure that you are using the write name when opening the file?

Comment: The code itself seems okay.  For debug purpose, you could print a readable character in the loop (maybe an extra counter).  As Martin commented: check the encoding of the file (notepad++ shows it on the right bottom, utf-8 should be okay).

Comment: I have uploaded the file (Note this is only the partial file as I am not allowed to upload the entire file). Im not sure if the file is unicode text or not.

Comment: Examine return value of `getline`. If it returns error, print out the error.

Comment: @hyde I am not sure what you mean by that? Or how to do that.

Comment: Hmm. To examine return value of `getline`, store it to a variable. Then print it or use debugger to see what it is. Then read the docs to understand what it means.

Comment: The uploaded file looks okay.  I don't see a reason why the code shouldn't print it unless there is something in the code that you didn't post (e.g. another implementation of getline (just writing std:: in the code would avoid this confusion)).

Comment: I found the problem. For some reason the code was not compiling the new added code for some reason. Problem solved. Thanks guys!